# Error Formatting Disk - Drive Missing

Tags: gdisk

So I had a somewhat faulty HDD (missed partition table) and plugged it in my linux in the SATA port. It was only showing as /dev/sda , no /sda1 whatsoever. In order to reformat its partition table I was following a tutorial and using gdisk, and I did this

```
Command (? for help): n 
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1 
First sector (34-1953525134, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 4096 
Last sector (4096-1953525134, default = 1953523711) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 1953523711
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem) 
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300):
  Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'
```

Afterwards I did `v` then `w`. And in `lsblk` /dev/sda started showing 0B instead of the expected 1Tb. `gdisk` said it had no space left on device.

I restarted to see if that would work and then it was gone from the `lsblk` output. And now it doesn't appear in anything else (tried `gdisk, fdisk, smartctl` and `dmesg`). No sd* letter assigned to it.

Is there any way for me to get it back or now it's gone for good?

I really don't know my way around filesystems and whatnot.

Comment: you could install `smartmontools` then use `smartctl` to troubleshoot it

Comment: Yuri, hi! What is the purpose of all this? The fact that you just went ahead and overwrote the partition table with your own suggest there was no data on the disk you needed to preserve. Is that correct? What you should depend **very** much depends on what you need.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, that is correct. If I manage to recover the data it's fine but if I don't... blimey. I'm more in need of a working disk than the data that was there. Not really sure how I would recover the missing partition anyway - I wasn't able to do anything to fix it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm in Fedora, the only way to install smartctl is to install smartmontools. I guess I've already done it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I apologize. I forgot to mention it. So blivet-gui is telling me "Error - Unknown error ocurred. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getFreeSpaceRegions'" when I click on it. I'm using a USB - SATA interface and it appears as sdb now.

Comment: @YuriTeixeiraMendes nevermind! That's OK :) See my answer.

Comment: *the only way to install smartctl is to install smartmontools* - which is **exactly** what I suggested, so, thanks for uncorrecting me

Comment: @JaromandaX I wasn't correcting you, just saying I already did what you suggested and it didn't solve the problem. It's in the question too. But if there's any smartctl test you'd like me to run so you can help me further, I'm all ears :) probably my regular off-the-internet tutorial was insufficient

Comment: sorry, was just trying to be amusing - and I didn't notice the mention of smartctl - my bad :p I guess it's hard to use smartctl for a device that doesn't even appear!!

Comment: @JaromandaX `systemctl status smartd` says the following about my /sdb: "opened -> not ATA, no IDENTIFY DEVICE Structure". Not really sure what that means but there you go. Maybe because I have no partition table?

Comment: a lack of partition table wouldn't stop the device from being seen

Answer (score 0):

Jaromanda is very right, you should worry a bit: hard drives do not simply "forget" their partition table. If your hard drive does that, *you should obviously not use it* – unless you want damaged data without noticing (that is **worse** than lost data).

First start `gnome-disks`, select your drive, and click the "three circles menu" (what a stupid UI design), then select "SMART Data & Self-Tests. There's a column "Assessment". And that should be all "OK". If it's not, then your hard drive has a problem and you should look into what that is.

Afterwards,  simply start `blivet-gui` (if it's not installed, you can install it using `sudo dnf install -y blivet-gui-runtime`), and use that make a new partition table, instead of following some advice that you copy and paste but not understand, that allows you to just actually make a new partition that you can see spans the whole device. Much easier. If your `blivet-gui` is quite new, it also helps you with choosing an appropriate file system for everyday use – if in doubt, use `ext4` when asked.

Comment: In `disks` the drive showed up, with only a small section in blue (didn't noticed the size). The "SMART Data" option isn't available. But I managed to use 'Format Disk' here. Whole drive seemed available, size appearing as normal. At blivet, the previous error stopped. I managed to format and make the partition table. But when I try to access the drive, Fedora isn't able to mount it. And after ejecting, it doesn't show up at files anymore. It remains 0B in lsblk, although now it has a drive letter (sdb).

Comment: A disk reporting its size as 0 bytes is one of the ways a disk can say "I'm dead, throw me away". Technically it means the disk is not passing its own internal self-tests any more.

Comment: @telcoM doesn't matter if the size was ok before I tried to redo the partition? Like, no possibility I was messing up with the wrong stuff and it's saying 0B because I misconfigured it? That's kinda of my original question.

Comment: Not really. A non-zero wrong size might be plausible if you had e.g. written an image of a smaller disk onto a larger one, but the only times I've ever seen disks reporting a 0B size in my 20+ years of system administration had been when those disks were having a terminal failure. You might get it running for a short while a few more times if you e.g. cool it down in a freezer before powering up, or various other tricks, but that's only really good for a last Hail Mary attempt to rescue some data that's not been properly backed up. Disks are wear items, you know.

Comment: @telcoM oh well. Thanks for the input.